# Use Request.Files in Classic ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, dhtmlx

I want to use dhtmlx vault control for file upload in classic asp. I've used his control in ASP.NET  & it works well. But in classic ASP, I'm not able to get files using Request.Files. Can anyone help me for this.

The code I'm using for file upload is:

```
                            var conf = {
                            container: "vaultObj",
                            uploadUrl: "vaultupload.asp",
                            autoStart: false,
                            skin: "dhx_skyblue"
                            };     

                           var myVault = new dhtmlXVaultObject(conf);
```

vaultupload.asp is the file on which I want to write code to upload images. But I'm not able to use Request object there. Do I have to include any assembly for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

file uploads are tricky in Classic ASP.  One option is to install a third party component like Persits ASP Upload or ABC Upload.

A popular solution is freeaspupload which uses a class file which you just upload to your server, you don't need to install anything.  It uses an ADODB stream object.  It used to be available an freeaspupload.net, but that site seems to be down at the moment, however the internet archive is your friend

https://web.archive.org/web/20140517095226/http://freeaspupload.net/

Comment: Thanks John, I checked freeaspupload. But it is not suitable for my requirement. I wwant to provide multiple file upload like we can do with jquery uploadify or dhtmlx vault control. Do you have idea about any such control that can help me?

Comment: @Priya Ofcourse it is suitable, freeaspupload gives you a raw upload facility that packages your files and form parameters into two collections `.Files` and `.Form` against the upload class. Multiple uploads doesn't stop this mechanic working you just call it multiple times using jquery with something like [Blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). It is entirely possible because I've done it using both the free upload script and this jquery plugin (but any ajax upload plugin will work).

Comment: There's an uploadify with freeaspupload script here http://www.uploadify.quickersite.com/

Comment: Thanks for replies. Finally I got success using uploadify plugin as suggested by John.Thanks again. :)